# Get Encoding list in .NET 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, .net-1.1

I need to retrieve a list of supported encodings, but I'm using **.NET 1.1**, so the following call is not available:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class SamplesEncoding
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      // For every encoding, get the property values.
      foreach( EncodingInfo ei in Encoding.GetEncodings() )
      {
         Encoding e = ei.GetEncoding();

         Console.Write("{0,-6} {1,-25} ", ei.CodePage, ei.Name);
         Console.Write("{0,-8} {1,-8} ", e.IsBrowserDisplay, e.IsBrowserSave);
         Console.Write("{0,-8} {1,-8} ", e.IsMailNewsDisplay, e.IsMailNewsSave);
         Console.WriteLine("{0,-8} {1,-8} ", e.IsSingleByte, e.IsReadOnly);
      }
   }
}
```

The call [`Encoding.GetEncodings()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencodings.aspx) is not available for .NET 1.1. Do you know any alternative method to get that list?

Comment: @dtb Are you another one of those people who post "Use Java" when someone posts a .Net question? ;-)

Comment: @dtb: My life would be much happier, but I can't

Comment: @Justin: Just one of those people who post "Use Windows XP" when someone posts a Windows 95 question in 2011. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite simple: .NET 1.1 is "fixed": it won't change. You take the Encodings of 2.0 and test if they were already present in 1.1. For example:

```
string[] encs = new string[] {
    "IBM037", "IBM437", "IBM500", "ASMO-708", "DOS-720", "ibm737",
    "ibm775", "ibm850", "ibm852", "IBM855", "ibm857", "IBM00858",
    "IBM860", "ibm861", "DOS-862", "IBM863", "IBM864", "IBM865",
    "cp866", "ibm869", "IBM870", "windows-874", "cp875",
    "shift_jis", "gb2312", "ks_c_5601-1987", "big5", "IBM1026",
    "IBM01047", "IBM01140", "IBM01141", "IBM01142", "IBM01143",
    "IBM01144", "IBM01145", "IBM01146", "IBM01147", "IBM01148",
    "IBM01149", "utf-16", "utf-16BE", "windows-1250",
    "windows-1251", "Windows-1252", "windows-1253", "windows-1254",
    "windows-1255", "windows-1256", "windows-1257", "windows-1258",
    "Johab", "macintosh", "x-mac-japanese", "x-mac-chinesetrad",
    "x-mac-korean", "x-mac-arabic", "x-mac-hebrew", "x-mac-greek",
    "x-mac-cyrillic", "x-mac-chinesesimp", "x-mac-romanian",
    "x-mac-ukrainian", "x-mac-thai", "x-mac-ce", "x-mac-icelandic",
    "x-mac-turkish", "x-mac-croatian", "utf-32", "utf-32BE",
    "x-Chinese-CNS", "x-cp20001", "x-Chinese-Eten", "x-cp20003",
    "x-cp20004", "x-cp20005", "x-IA5", "x-IA5-German",
    "x-IA5-Swedish", "x-IA5-Norwegian", "us-ascii", "x-cp20261",
    "x-cp20269", "IBM273", "IBM277", "IBM278", "IBM280", "IBM284",
    "IBM285", "IBM290", "IBM297", "IBM420", "IBM423", "IBM424",
    "x-EBCDIC-KoreanExtended", "IBM-Thai", "koi8-r", "IBM871",
    "IBM880", "IBM905", "IBM00924", "EUC-JP", "x-cp20936",
    "x-cp20949", "cp1025", "koi8-u", "iso-8859-1", "iso-8859-2",
    "iso-8859-3", "iso-8859-4", "iso-8859-5", "iso-8859-6",
    "iso-8859-7", "iso-8859-8", "iso-8859-9", "iso-8859-13",
    "iso-8859-15", "x-Europa", "iso-8859-8-i", "iso-2022-jp",
    "csISO2022JP", "iso-2022-jp", "iso-2022-kr", "x-cp50227",
    "euc-jp", "EUC-CN", "euc-kr", "hz-gb-2312", "GB18030",
    "x-iscii-de", "x-iscii-be", "x-iscii-ta", "x-iscii-te",
    "x-iscii-as", "x-iscii-or", "x-iscii-ka", "x-iscii-ma",
    "x-iscii-gu", "x-iscii-pa", "utf-7", "utf-8"
};
```

and

```
foreach (string enc in encs)
{
    try {
        Encoding.GetEncoding(enc);
    } catch {
        Console.WriteLine("Missing {0}", enc);
    }
}
```

(yes, that is the full list of encodings present in .NET 4.0... If you need them in "numeric" value, it would be quite easy to do it). Then you take the ones that don't work and take them away from that list.

To generate them (minimum .NET 2.0 and C# 3.0):

```
var encs = Encoding.GetEncodings().Select(p => p.Name);
//var encs = Encoding.GetEncodings().Select(p => p.CodePage);

var sb = new StringBuilder("var encs = new[] {");

foreach (var enc in encs) {
    sb.Append(" \"" + enc + "\",");
    //sb.Append(" " + enc + ",");
}

sb.Length--;

sb.Append(" };");

var str = sb.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: The `var` part in foreach is not valid for .NET 1.1. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I haven't completely misunderstood the situation (quite possible), the following should work if you have about a minute or two to wait for it. It is really slow, not to mention a bit ugly.

```
public static Encoding[] GetList()
{
    ArrayList arrayList;
    arrayList = new ArrayList();
    for ( int i = 0; i < 65535; i++ )
    {
        try
        {
            arrayList.Add( Encoding.GetEncoding( i ) );
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
    return (Encoding[])arrayList.ToArray( typeof( Encoding ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that you should use `Encoding.GetEnconding(int CodePage)` where `CodePage` should be one of:

The following Windows code pages exist:

```
874 — Thai
932 — Japanese
936 — Chinese (simplified) (PRC, Singapore)
949 — Korean
950 — Chinese (traditional) (Taiwan, Hong Kong)
1200 — Unicode (BMP of ISO 10646, UTF-16LE)
1201 — Unicode (BMP of ISO 10646, UTF-16BE)
1250 — Latin (Central European languages)
1251 — Cyrillic
1252 — Latin (Western European languages)
1253 — Greek
1254 — Turkish
1255 — Hebrew
1256 — Arabic
1257 — Latin (Baltic languages)
1258 — Vietnamese
65000 — Unicode (BMP of ISO 10646, UTF-7)
65001 — Unicode (BMP of ISO 10646, UTF-8)
```

[Taken from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page)